# SSH for "svn add --all" command line

Tags: svn, command-line

When using Git I usually use `git add --all` and then commit. I'm using SSH SVN through a terminal, and I want to add a file, but what is the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn add <file>`; the file then is "marked" for addition. Next time you commit, the file will be added to the repository.

So if you want to only add one file into the repository, use `svn add <file>` followed by `svn commit <file>`.

Comment: SVN has a separate action for adding files: `svn add` will add a file which is NOT yet versionised (not yet in repository). Changed files as well as all "pending" actions are put into the repository as soon as they are committed, using `svn commit`. `svn status` shows you what happened inside your working copy and what will happen as soon as you `svn commit`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `svn add` is different from `git add` in that `svn add` adds **new** files (and folders), whereas `git add` adds **new files and modifications to tracked files**.

So after adding files in SVN, doing a `svn commit` (without a specific path) will commit the modifications as well. There is no need to add modified files in SVN for a commit. And you also have to be careful about exactly what you are committing.

Answer (score 0):

First, add the file to the repository using `svn add filename`. Then you actually have to commit it to the server, which I'm sure you know how to do. (`svn commit filename`)